# Network stats gatherer (loadable kernel module) isn't working?

Tags: device-driver, kernel-module

I'm kinda new to linux kernel modules and I'm trying to write my own module that gives me some statistics about a device ( the NIC here). 
although I'm using kernel 2.6.35 and I've included `linux/netdevices`, compiling keeps saying that the function `ndo_get_stats` is implicitly declared. can anyone tell me what's going on ?

here's the module, simple I know,

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/netdevice.h>    /* Needed for netdevice*/




static int __init hello_start(void)
{
     struct net_device *dev;
     struct net_device_stats *devstats;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Stats module...\n");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello world\n");
    dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
    while (dev)
    {
         printk(KERN_INFO "found [%s] and it's [%d]\n", dev->name, dev->flags & IFF_UP);

         printk(KERN_INFO "End of dev struct ... now starts the get_stats struct\n");

     devstats = ndo_get_stats(dev);

     printk(KERN_INFO "recive errors: [%li]\n transmission errors: [%li]\n number of collisions: [%li]", devstats->rx_errors , devstats->tx_errors, devstats->collisions);

      dev = next_net_device(dev);
     }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye.\n");
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [why am I getting an "implicit declaration of function 'ndo_get_stats' " error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084964/why-am-i-getting-an-implicit-declaration-of-function-ndo-get-stats-error)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084964/why-am-i-getting-an-implicit-declaration-of-function-ndo-get-stats-error


found answer here..