# why am I getting an "implicit declaration of function 'ndo_get_stats' " error?

Tags: linux, device-driver, kernel-module

I'm building a VERY SIMPLE kernel module for gathering some stats from the network card here's the code, I keep getting an error `implicit declaration of function 'ndo_get_stats'`. I'm not sure why...

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/netdevice.h>    /* Needed for netdevice*/



static int __init hello_start(void)
{
    struct net_device *dev;



    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Stats module...\n");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello world\n");
    dev = first_net_device(&init_net);
    while (dev)
    {
         printk(KERN_INFO "found [%s] and it's [%d]\n", dev->name, dev->flags & IFF_UP);

         printk(KERN_INFO "End of dev struct ... now starts the get_stats struct\n");

     dev->stats = ndo_get_stats(dev);

     printk(KERN_INFO "recive errors: [%li]\n transmission errors: [%li]\n number of collisions: [%li]", dev->stats.rx_errors , dev->stats.tx_errors, dev->stats.collisions);

      dev = next_net_device(dev);
     }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye.\n");
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndo_get_stats` is a `net_device_ops` function pointer. You have to call it through the `netdev_ops` field of your `net_device`.

Something like this would work:

```
stats = dev->netdev_ops->ndo_get_stats(dev);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but...
`incompatible types to assigning type struct net_device_stats from net_device_stats*` still not working

Comment: Please post your updated code. Are you trying to do 'struct net_device_stats stats = dev->netdev_ops->nd_get_stats(dev);'? Note that nd_get_stats returns a pointer to struct_dev_device_stats.

Comment: Also note that what you're trying to do is probably invalid. You're not allowed to overwrite the stats field of the net_device. That's managed by the net_device itself.

Comment: I only edited this line:
`dev->stats = ndo_get_stats(dev);`
to become:
`dev->stats = dev->netdev_ops->ndo_get_stats(dev);`

Comment: As I said, that's invalid. The dev->stats field is managed by the device itself. You're not even allowed to read it. You need to create a struct net_device_stats *stats, and assign the result of ndo_get_stats to that to read the statistics.

Comment: the only reason I'm overwriting the stats field is because it's always empty, I read that it gets filled after calling ndo_get_stats method

Comment: While I'm criticizing: I think you're better off staying in userspace. You can call ndo_get_stats() indirectly, through netlink. (The general rule for writing kernel code is that you shouldn't do it. Only if what you're trying to to is absolutely impossible from user space should you be trying to do it from the kernel.)